# The controller is not callable

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

Hello all I'm migrating symfony to version 5.4 and I'm having a problem with a controller:

`The controller for URI "/api/resetting/tokentest/reset.json" is not callable: Controller "WOOD\UserBundle\Controller\ResettingRESTController" cannot be fetched from the container because it is private. Did you forget to tag the service with "controller.service_arguments"?`

As specified in the documentation, I added the controller.service_arguments tag but the problem still occurs. Do you have an idea please?

`# Form factory WOOD\UserBundle\Controller\ResettingRESTController: '@fos_user.profile.form.factory' tags: ['controller.service_arguments']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't understand the error message. You need to create an alias for the fos resetting service and not for your class.

```
# Form factory
FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FormFactory:
    '@fos_user.resetting.form.factory'
```